# How can I enable "clicklock"?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I've been looking for a while now a way to get the "click lock" in ubuntu 13.10 (for dragging) but so far, I have no success. Universal access lacks this feature, and I have not found some program or utility that allows me simulate it.

According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24558/where-is-the-accessibility-mouse-click-lock?rq=1), it seems that in ubuntu 10.10 there was no way to get it working, but I wonder if this issue has been addressed in the latest versions.

With this command,`xte "mousedown 1"` I get the desired functionality, but still you would need to type the command on a terminal or bind it to a key. Is there a way to get the same functionality by long pressing the button click?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: According to "which" question,if you can't post the link in question, post it in comment and we would take care of it.

Comment: @AdityaPatil sorry, I didn't notice the link wasn't included in the question. The question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/24558/where-is-the-accessibility-mouse-click-lock?rq=1.

Comment: By lock click do you mean that once you click(or do something) it will work as if you have clicked and not released the mouse button?

Comment: @AdityaPatil yes, with Lock click you can drag and highlight without having to keep the mouse button pressed. In Windows, you just press for a moment the mouse button, to release it, you just click again.

Comment: I have something that may help, I'll write an answer.

Comment: For the Windows "Click Lock" similar feature on Ubuntu, you can have a look at: http://blog.mbirgin.com/?c=page&ID=550&t=lockeddragsclicklockinubuntulinux

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `kmousetool`.According to `man kmousetool`,

> > KMouseTool clicks the mouse whenever the mouse cursor pauses briefly.
> >
> > KMouseTool can also be configured to wait for a specified time for a drag to begin, before unclicking the mouse. This way, you can use it for drag and drop operations as well.

To install `kmousetool`, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install kmousetool
```

Open `kmousetool` and you will see a window like this.
[image]

Here enable **Smart drag** and let the defaults "as is" for now. Click **Apply** and then click **Start**. You are ready to go.

This app requires a bit of practice and may seem hard to use at first, but with proper settings(which you may choose to change once you get acquainted) and a bit of practice, this can become a handy tool for anyone.

Comment: Hi, it's not exactly what I want, as you say it's difficult to use. Especially, given that is not based on the left click by itself, but instead whenever I put the cursor and leave  the mouse, a click is simulated, which makes it really hard to use. I'll give it a try for now, but hoping there is a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this obscure git repo is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/germag/clicklockd

```
git clone https://github.com/germag/clicklockd.git
cd clicklockd
make
sudo ./clicklockd -t 2 -b
```

And it works exactly as Windows ClickLock feature. Took me years of frustration and sudden luck to find it, it is not really simple to implement it correctly.

Comment: When I run make, I get `event_loop.c:31:21: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory.` How to solve this problem?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` solved the problem on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks to the author of `https://github.com/germag/clicklockd`