# Mouse clicklock needed for accessibility! Where is it?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, mouse, accessibility, xorg.conf

Here's a news article: [*Windows-Only Click Lock Feature to Be Built for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*](http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-only-click-lock-feature-to-be-built-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts-495904.shtml)

I have a disability and I really need this feature to fully use the computer.

I've heard rumors that it used to be included in an old distro (I've tried 14.04 and 8.04, not there). Does anyone know how to get it back or how to implement it? I think it might be in xorg …

Comment: According to [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/26004/147763), `sudo apt install xautomation` followed by adding a keybinding so that, when the mouse button is pressed, `xte "mousedown 1"` is executed will do what you want. I don't use Unity, so I'm unsure how to do the keybinding.

Answer (score 3):

this obscure git repo is what you're looking for.

https://github.com/germag/clicklockd

```
git clone https://github.com/germag/clicklockd.git
cd clicklockd
make
sudo ./clicklockd -t 2 -b
```

And it works exactly as Windows ClickLock feature. Took me years of frustration and sudden luck to find it, it is not really simple to implement it correctly.